# I'm attempting to parse json data from zendesk using v: structure

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

With standard fields, like id, this works perfectly. But I am not finding a way to parse the custom fields where the structure is

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 57852188,
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 57522467,
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 57522487,
      "value": ""
    }
]
```

The general format that I have been using is:

```
 Select v:id,v:updatedat
 from zd_tickets
```

updated data:

```
{ 
    "id":151693, 
    "brand_id": 36000, 
    "created_at": "2022-0523T19:26:35Z", 
    "custom_fields": [
        { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, 
        { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" },
        { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ], 
    "group_id": 36000770 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all repeating elements you will need to use FLATTEN, otherwise you can use standard notation. This is all documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#retrieving-a-single-instance-of-a-repeating-element

Comment: My variant record only contains 1 data record, so I don't believe FLATTEN needs to be used? 
I'm able to pull the non-custom fields with no problem, it is just the custom fields that do not seem to work in a similar fashion.
Here is a limited example:

{
 "id":151693,
 "brand_id": 36000,
 "created_at": "2022-0523T19:26:35Z",
 "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 57866008,
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "id": 360022282754,
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 80814087,
      "value": "NC"
    }
],
"group_id": 36000770
}

Answer (score 1):

So using this CTE to access the data in a way that look like a table:

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json(column1) from values
    ('{ 
    "id":151693, 
    "brand_id": 36000, 
    "created_at": "2022-0523T19:26:35Z", 
    "custom_fields": [
        { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, 
        { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" },
        { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ], 
    "group_id": 36000770 
} ')
)
```

SQL to unpack the top level items, as you have shown you have working:

```
select
    json:id::number as id
    ,json:brand_id::number as brand_id
    ,try_to_timestamp(json:created_at::text, 'yyyy-mmddThh:mi:ssZ') as created_at
    ,json:custom_fields as custom_fields
from data;
```

gives:

| ID | BRAND_ID | CREATED_AT | CUSTOM_FIELDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151693 | 36000 | 2022-05-23 19:26:35.000 | [ { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" }, { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ] |

So now how to tackle that json/array of custom_fields..

Well if you only ever have 3 values, and the order is always the same..

```
select
    to_array(json:custom_fields) as custom_fields_a
    ,custom_fields_a[0] as field_0
    ,custom_fields_a[1] as field_1
    ,custom_fields_a[2] as field_2
from data;
```

gives:

| CUSTOM_FIELDS_A | FIELD_0 | FIELD_1 | FIELD_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" }, { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ] | { "id": 57866008, "value": false } | { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" } | { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } |

so we can use flatten to access those objects, which makes "more rows"

```
select
    d.json:id::number as id
    ,d.json:brand_id::number as brand_id
    ,try_to_timestamp(d.json:created_at::text, 'yyyy-mmddThh:mi:ssZ') as created_at
    ,f.*
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>json:custom_fields)) f
```

| ID | BRAND_ID | CREATED_AT | SEQ | KEY | PATH | INDEX | VALUE | THIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151693 | 36000 | 2022-05-23 19:26:35.000 | 1 |  | [0] | 0 | { "id": 57866008, "value": false } | [ { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" }, { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ] |
| 151693 | 36000 | 2022-05-23 19:26:35.000 | 1 |  | [1] | 1 | { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" } | [ { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" }, { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ] |
| 151693 | 36000 | 2022-05-23 19:26:35.000 | 1 |  | [2] | 2 | { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } | [ { "id": 57866008, "value": false }, { "id": 360022282754, "value": "" }, { "id": 80814087, "value": "NC" } ] |

So we can pull out know values (a manual PIVOT)

```
select
    d.json:id::number as id
    ,d.json:brand_id::number as brand_id
    ,try_to_timestamp(d.json:created_at::text, 'yyyy-mmddThh:mi:ssZ') as created_at
    ,max(iff(f.value:id=80814087, f.value:value::text, null)) as v80814087
    ,max(iff(f.value:id=360022282754, f.value:value::text, null)) as v360022282754
    ,max(iff(f.value:id=57866008, f.value:value::text, null)) as v57866008
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>json:custom_fields)) f
group by 1,2,3, f.seq
```

grouping by the `f.seq` means if you have many "rows" of input these will be kept apart, even if they share common values for `1,2,3`

gives:

| ID | BRAND_ID | CREATED_AT | V80814087 | V360022282754 | V57866008 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151693 | 36000 | 2022-05-23 19:26:35.000 | NC | <empty string> | false |

Now if you do not know the names of the values, there is no way short of dynamic SQL and double parsing to turns rows into columns.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have only 3 values, I have 184. However,  they are always in the same order (When we pull the data into a json record, it just assigns a null value if the field wasn't used for that record.
I'm working to implement the code that you illustrated into CTEs so I can perform all of this using 1 view- will follow up after I have succeeded.
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what the unfortunately part is, I would bust out some Python/JavaScript, and give a "list generate" the full SQL following one of those patterns (known position is easier/faster, but it really needs to be stable).. and then save/checkin the generated SQL.

Comment: The flatten is problematic with 184 fields (1.8 million records created out of under 10k, and that is nowhere near the true dataset's size). Is it possible to select only the columns that I want for the flatten? Suppose, for example, that I only want columns 0 and 2 from the example set above?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following, with 2 different CTEs (CTE and UCF):

1. Used to_array to gather my custom fields
2. Unioned the custom fields together twice; once for the id of the field and once for the value (and used combinations of substring, position and replace to clean up data as needed (same setup for all fields)
3. Joined the resulting data to a Custom Fields Table (contains the id and a name) to include the name of the custom field in my result set.

WITH UCF AS (--Union Gathered Array into 2 fields (an id field and a value field)
WITH CTE AS(  ---Gather array of custom fields

```
SELECT v:id as id,
to_array(v:custom_fields) as cf
   ,cf[0] as f0,cf[1] as f1,cf[2] as f2
FROM ZD_TICKETS)

SELECT id,
substring(f0,7,position(',',f0)-7) AS cf_id,  REPLACE(substring(f0,position('value":',f0)+8,position('"',f0,position('value":',f0)+8)),'"}') AS cf_value
FROM CTE c
WHERE f0 not like '%null%'
UNION
SELECT id,
substring(f1,7,position(',',f1)-7) AS cf_id,
REPLACE(substring(f1,position('value":',f1)+8,position('"',f1,position('value":',f1)+8)),'"}') AS cf_value
FROM CTE c
WHERE f1 not like '%null%'
-- field 3
UNION
SELECT id,
substring(f2,7,position(',',f2)-7) AS cf_id,
REPLACE(substring(f2,position('value":',f2)+8,position('"',f2,position('value":',f2)+8)),'"}') AS cf_value
FROM CTE c
WHERE f2 not like '%null%' --this removes records where the value is null
)
SELECT UCF.*,CFD.name FROM UCF
LEFT OUTER JOIN "FLBUSINESS_DB"."STAGING"."FILE_ZD_CUSTOM_FIELD_IDS" CFD
 ON CFD.id=UCF.cf_id
 WHERE cf_value<>''  --this removes records where the value is blank
```

The result set looks like:
[image]